# `cv::findContours` method doesn't work properly when detect text regions on white background. (OpenCV)

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour

What problem I face is that when I run the opencv code to detect contours in an image,I can't get inside the boundary of the image and thus the program gets me a contour on the boundary of the image.

```
 Mat3b xyres;
cvtColor(img, xyres, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
for (int i = 0; i < rects.size(); ++i)
{
    rectangle(xyres, rects[i], Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
}

Size size2(700, 800);
        resize(xyres, xyres, size2);
imshow("XY-Cut Result", xyres);

waitKey();
```

The image output looks something like this:
[image]

I need something like this:[image]

Comment: Can you attach the original input image as well ?

Answer (score 2):

We do `findContours` for `white objects on black background`.

While your binary image is `black chars on white background`, you should `threshold` it with flag `THRESH_BINARY_INV` to get white on black. Then do `findContours`.