# OpenCV : findContours method not working properly

Tags: java, opencv

I have made project where I used to read a picture and then detect the contours inside it and then return the largest area detected.

But I tried with this picture (bellow) it's seems it didn't work as I wanted,
Normally it should return the t-shirt area but instead it returned another area

Here's the code

```
Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread(imageURL);
Mat gray = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(img, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Imgproc.Canny(gray, gray, 100, 200, 3, false);
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
Imgproc.findContours(gray, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
double maxVal = 0;
int maxValIdx = 0;
for (int contourIdx = 0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++)
{
    double contourArea = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(contourIdx));
    if (maxVal < contourArea)
    {
        maxVal = contourArea;
        maxValIdx = contourIdx;
    }
}

Imgproc.drawContours(img, contours, maxValIdx, new Scalar(0,255,0), 5);
```

Here's the input picture
[image: tshirt.jpg]

And this is the output
[image: tshirt.jpg]

Is there any mistake i made in the code ? is there a better way to resolve this ?

Comment: We do `findContour` for `white objects on black background`. A similar question: [cvfindcontours-method-doesnt-work-properly-when-detect-text-regions-on-whit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48314605/cvfindcontours-method-doesnt-work-properly-when-detect-text-regions-on-whit/48315201#48315201)

Comment: and what about this example http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2013/09/find-contour.html ?